# Annotating text data with ontologies

Tags: annotations, data-annotations, ontology-network

I have a list of plant organisms (text) and I want to annotate them with ontologies(Plant ontology, Crop Ontology, Food Ontology, etc), I was using ontology lookup services to do the annotation manually but it taking soo much time, the list is about 7,000. Is there a tool, code, like that can help me do this faster. thank you.

I tried Zooma ontology annotation and NCBO bioportal annotator +, but it does not give me ontology expect the NCBI term

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.